# SSL script issue

Tags: apache, ssl, scripting

I am currently using this htaccess code to force all users to use ssl :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

However my website uses many scripts to load variety of images and i get tons off errors like this one :

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://website.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://website.com/3.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

Is there a way of forcing scripts to load https images or i have to edit them manually ?

Comment: mod_rewrite regexes don't use `=`. `!=on` is `NOT the string '=on'`. you want just `!on`, which is literally `NOT 'on'`

Comment: You have to edit them manually. It does not change the hardcoded links on your page. If you are now using `https` you need to update your links accordingly or you're going to get the insecure warning.  I mean that what web devs have to do. :) You can't have your page also load http content via https request.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to edit them manually. Of course, if any of those resources, i. e. other sources than yours, don't have https-alternatives, you will always get errors. With newer versions of some browsers those scripts will actually be blocked, and not loaded at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your script URLs to use the protocol relative format. Modern browsers understand that they should load the script using whatever protocol (https or http) you're using in the calling page.

Example:

Change `<script src=”https://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>`

To `<script src=”//ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js” type=”text/javascript”></script>`

Article explaining:
http://blog.httpwatch.com/2010/02/10/using-protocol-relative-urls-to-switch-between-http-and-https/